# Why WSO2 API Manager sometimes go into error: Proxy ErrorThe proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am very new in **WSO2 AM** and I have the following problem.

I registered an API on the publisher and I obtained it in the store. Following the organization policy I created an application that generate a **Bearer** token and I subscribed my API to this application.

So I use this token to perform my request, something like this:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer 7cc2337d64ca7238ec3534c251f72e34" -d @user_registration_sample_3.json "https://api.myorganization.org/api/dsa/v1.0.0/user_registration"
```

I tested it and it worked. It called my backend API and correctly returned the result to the client. The problem is that after some request it started to go into error and I stop to obtain request. Sometimes works, sometimes not.

When it goes into error I obtain this message:

```
$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer 7cc2337d64ca7238ec3534c251f72e34" -d @user_registration_sample_3.json "https://api.myorganization.org/api/dsa/v1.0.0/user_registration"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   644  100   444  100   200      3      1  0:03:20  0:02:00  0:01:20    64<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/api/dsa/v1.0.0/user_registration">POST&nbsp;/api/dsa/v1.0.0/user_registration</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

So I am trying to do some troubleshooting but I have know idea about the possible causes of this issue.

I think that the problem is not in my backend (if I directly call my backend endpoints it works fine and I never obtained error, but I am not totaly sure of this) so the problem should be in the API manager. It sotps to work, after some times it return to work. My backend is a set of APIs developed using WSO2 ESB and deployed on a WSO2 EI instance.

I also thought that this could be a problem related to the number of requests addressed to the API manager (maybe there is some configuration that says something like: "after 5 requests --> wait some time". But I think that it should be not the problem because the **Tiew Availability** of my API is setted on **Unlimited**. Also my token is setted to not expire (the expiration time of the token is setted to the **-1** value that means no expire).

So do you think that can be a systemistic problem? (from what I know the WSO2 infrastracture is deployed in a cluster, maybe some node of the clouster is not working and when the broken node receive the request can't handle it) or network problem?

What exaclty means the previous error message: what is this **proxy server** and what is the **upstream server**?

Comment: Do you have an Apache web server fronting the WSO2 API Manager server? Or do you front the backends with Apache web server?

Comment: @Pubci the API manager call some APIs developed using the ESB and deployed on a WSO2 EI instance. so there is no an apache web server fronting my APIs. what do you mean exactly with "an Apache web server fronting the WSO2 API Manager"?

Comment: You can front API Manager gateways with Apache server... Anyway, this response is coming from EI.. Check for the timeout settings https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Endpoint+Error+Handling#EndpointErrorHandling-timeoutSettings

Comment: Difficult to say without debugging the whole traffic. Is it possible that you use http instead of https between caller <-> api manager <-> esb? If so, I would enable wire logs (org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=debug) or put something like tcpmon (https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html) between caller,api and esb (and maybe the between esb and backend) to see  whats really going on.